# Blank space next to Divs with clear: left element

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a responsive website using HTML and CSS, and I have created four `div` elements in a container width of 50%, each of these elements are 25% width and 25% height. Making a square. Next to these four div's is another div, 50% in width. When I try to get the two containers to go side side, they appear incorrect. The image below will demonstrate this clearly.

[image]

**What I am trying to achieve.**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML Code

```
<div id="tile-1-small-left-1">

</div>
<div id="tile-1-small-left-2">

</div>
<div id="tile-1-small-left-3">

</div>
<div id="tile-1-small-left-4">

</div>

<div id="tile-1-small-right">

</div>
```

**The CSS code:**

```
#tile-1-small-left-1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#tile-1-small-left-2 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#tile-1-small-left-3 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
#tile-1-small-left-4 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#tile-1-small-right{
    /*background-image: url(../img/hero_rotation.jpg);*/
    background-color: purple;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 45%;
}
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xjsjqn8m/)**

Comment: How set in stone is your markup? Some study of modern responsive grid techniques demonstrates that you typically need one more level of structure to do what you're after.

Comment: Your fiddle does not look at all like your screenshot. Not just the shapes, also the colors.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The image should show that the `separate div` should be halfway between `div 4` and `div 2`.

Comment: If you move the right div in the markup to before the first left div, the result is already pretty much like you wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/xjsjqn8m/1/

Comment: @MrLister Thank you! Your solution worked great! Clearly need to get my structuring right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, this usually calls for another level of structure. This would do, based on your original CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#tile-1-small-left-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#tile-1-small-left-2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#tile-1-small-left-3 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

#tile-1-small-left-4 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.tile-1-small-right {
  /*background-image: url(../img/hero_rotation.jpg);*/
  background-color: purple;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-1-small-right">

</div>
<div class="tile-1-small-right">
  <div id="tile-1-small-left-1">

  </div>
  <div id="tile-1-small-left-2">

  </div>
  <div id="tile-1-small-left-3">

  </div>
  <div id="tile-1-small-left-4">

  </div>
</div>
```

What I've done is wrapped the four smaller elements in another instance of the larger element (which required changing your selector to a class rather than an ID).

This case also demonstrates why ID-based selectors are a bad idea, and why semantic class names should be used. Calling something `-left` becomes confusing as soon as that type of element gets used elsewhere in the page.

Comment: You don't have to enclose the left divs in a container. See https://jsfiddle.net/xjsjqn8m/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solution has worked, also a few others had mentioned this way too. Clearly I need to get my structuring on par! Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @MrLister, true, but this is a path to a much more reusable and scalable grid.

Answer (score 0):

For the first image example, just add `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

```
<div id="tile-1-small-left-4"></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div id="tile-1-small-right"></div>
```